# Root Locus of the system

Tags: pole-zeroplot, root-locus

[image: Root Locus]

How can I plot root locus like these system can you help me?

Comment: You have already asked this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/541012/s-domain-function-z-domain-root-locus

Comment: transform C(z) to s plane, using bilinear approximation etc. then proceed as normal

Comment: @Pete W the question requires the RL for C(z)G(z)

Comment: @Chu - oh, sry misread it. Then this is the exact same question the OP posted just a day or two ago. I am not familiar with doing it in z plane, but would it be true that the stability condition for the underlying s-plane system doesn't change with the transform? (the gain otoh ... ?) i think we can always convert between s and z poles/zeros (but it is one-to-many in both directions). it has been a long time since i learned this

Comment: ok Hans, looked it up for you ... [it is the same in the z plane](http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/nov17.pdf).

Comment: If I computed correctly, just do the root locus in the \$z\$ plane with the sampler removed and the ZOH, \$G(s)\$ replaced by \${ (e-1)z^{-1} \over e-z^{-1}} \$.

Answer (score 1):

With \$\small T=1\$, the Laplace transform of the sampler and ZOH is \$\large\frac{1-e^{-s}}{s}\$. This is partitioned into a \$z\$ term, \$\small (1-z^{-1})=\large \frac{z-1}{z}\$, and an \$s\$ term, \$\large \frac{1}{s}\$.

Combine the \$z\$ term with \$\small C(z)\$ and the \$s\$ term with \$\small G(s)\$, then determine the z-transform of the resultant s-TF, \$\large \frac{G(s)}{s}\$, via table look-up. Hence, determine the overall ZTF of the forward path.